What's wrong with this use of \whiledo?
Ref.: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/729600/
What is wrong with the following definition from nfssext-cfr-nfss.sty?
\newcommand*\exfs@unmerge@families[1]{%
        \edef\exfs@tempf{#1}%
        \edef\tempa{\expandafter\exfs@get@variants\f@family\@nil}%
        \let\exfs@tempq\@empty
        \edef\exfs@tempg{}%
        \setcounter{taken}{0}%
        % check whether there are variants - if not do nothing
        \ifx\tempa\@empty
                \edef\exfs@tempq{}%
        \else
                % o/w go through the variants to find the one to delete
                \whiledo{\value{taken}<1}{%
                        % get the next variant
                        \edef\exfs@tempn{\expandafter\exfs@next\tempa\@nil}%
                        % see if the next variant is the thing we seek and, if so, eliminate it
                        \ifx\exfs@tempf\exfs@tempn
                                \edef\tempa{\expandafter\exfs@shift\tempa\@nil}%
                                \edef\exfs@tempq{\exfs@tempg\tempa}%
                                \stepcounter{taken}%
                        % o/w save the next variant and move on if any variants remain
                        \else
                                \edef\exfs@tempg{\exfs@tempg\exfs@tempn}%
                                \edef\tempa{\expandafter\exfs@shift\tempa\@nil}%
                                \ifx\tempa\@empty% if there are no variants left, we're done
                                        \edef\exfs@tempq{\exfs@tempg}%
                                        \stepcounter{taken}%
                                \fi
                        \fi
                }%
        \fi
        \exfs@try@family{\expandafter\exfs@get@base\f@family\@nil \exfs@tempq}}

MNWE on current kernels:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{taken}%
\renewcommand*\exfs@unmerge@families[1]{%
        \edef\exfs@tempf{#1}%
        \edef\tempa{\expandafter\exfs@get@variants\f@family\@nil}%
        \let\exfs@tempq\@empty
        \edef\exfs@tempg{}%
        \setcounter{taken}{0}%
        % check whether there are variants - if not do nothing
        \ifx\tempa\@empty
                \edef\exfs@tempq{}%
        \else
                % o/w go through the variants to find the one to delete
                \whiledo{\value{taken}<1}{%
                        % get the next variant
                        \edef\exfs@tempn{\expandafter\exfs@next\tempa\@nil}%
                        % see if the next variant is the thing we seek and, if so, eliminate it
                        \ifx\exfs@tempf\exfs@tempn
                                \edef\tempa{\expandafter\exfs@shift\tempa\@nil}%
                                \edef\exfs@tempq{\exfs@tempg\tempa}%
                                \stepcounter{taken}%
                        % o/w save the next variant and move on if any variants remain
                        \else
                                \edef\exfs@tempg{\exfs@tempg\exfs@tempn}%
                                \edef\tempa{\expandafter\exfs@shift\tempa\@nil}%
                                \ifx\tempa\@empty% if there are no variants left, we're done
                                        \edef\exfs@tempq{\exfs@tempg}%
                                        \stepcounter{taken}%
                                \fi
                        \fi
                }%
        \fi
        \exfs@try@family{\expandafter\exfs@get@base\f@family\@nil \exfs@tempq}}
\makeatother
$\text{123}$

$\text{\tstyle 123}$
\end{document}

Would it be safe to substitute the following (from nfssext-cfr-nnfss.sty) on pre-2021 kernels?
\newif\ifexfs@take
\newcommand*\exfs@unmerge@families[1]{%
  \edef\exfs@tempf{#1}%
  \edef\tempa{\expandafter\exfs@get@variants\f@family\@nil}%
  \let\exfs@tempq\@empty
  \edef\exfs@tempg{}%
  \exfs@taketrue
  \ifx\tempa\@empty
    \edef\exfs@tempq{}%
  \else
    \loop
      \edef\exfs@tempn{\expandafter\exfs@next\tempa\@nil}%
      \ifx\exfs@tempf\exfs@tempn
        \edef\tempa{\expandafter\exfs@shift\tempa\@nil}%
        \edef\exfs@tempq{\exfs@tempg\tempa}%
        \exfs@takefalse
      \else
        \edef\exfs@tempg{\exfs@tempg\exfs@tempn}%
        \edef\tempa{\expandafter\exfs@shift\tempa\@nil}%
        \ifx\tempa\@empty% if there are no variants left, we're done
          \edef\exfs@tempq{\exfs@tempg}%
          \exfs@takefalse
        \fi
      \fi
      \ifexfs@take % \fi yn \repeat
    \repeat
  \fi
  \exfs@try@family{\expandafter\exfs@get@base\f@family\@nil \exfs@tempq}%
}

Right now, this second definition is used only on newer kernels. While it is highly unlikely anybody will use an updated version on a pre-2021 kernel, I would prefer to fix it, if possible. However, I don't have an easy way to test it. (I guess I could install TL 2019.) I've been reluctant to change the code for older versions of LaTeX for fear of changing/breaking something, so have mostly left the code alone even in cases where it does something at odds with the documentation. So I could easily be persuaded not to touch this.

\expandafter\exfs@next\tempa\@nil doesn't like it if \tempa is empty

@UlrikeFischer hmm. so since that's in both definitions, it shouldn't work at all?

@UlrikeFischer oh, the second one cycles differently.
